# PigServer.java in local mode tries to use chmod command

Tags: apache-pig

Good day!

I try to use PigServer.java. Here is my code:

```
 PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.LOCAL);
 final Map<String, String> predefinedParams = getPredefinedParams();
 pigServer.debugOn();
 pigServer.setBatchOn();        
 pigServer.registerScript(DEST_SCRIPT.getAbsolutePath(), predefinedParams);
 pigServer.executeBatch();        
 pigServer.shutdown();
```

When I ran it on WinXp all worked fine. But when I try it on Win7 the exception occurs:

```
ERROR mapReduceLayer.Launcher: Backend error message during job submission
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
................
```

Here is the content of my pig script:

```
result = LOAD '$data' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (user, time, query); 
STORE result INTO '$output' USING PigStorage();
```

Do you have any ideas, why does this occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have cygwin on your WindowsXP host, but not on the Windows 7 one?

http://javaprotlib.sourceforge.net/packages/io/howtofixhadoop.html gives advice which might help you.